# pandas compare 2 columns and only keep matching words strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to compare words or stings in 1 dataframe column with another column in the same df and output a 3rd column with only the matching words.

```
input
Col1
the cat crossed a road
the dog barked
the chicken barked

Col2
the cat alligator
some words here
chicken soup

desired result
Col3
the cat
NULL
chicken
```

This is what I have but getting an error.

```
df[Col3] = df[Col1].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word in x[Col2].split(' ')]))
```

error is
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply`, with an `' '.join`, and than use a list comprehension to get the values that match

Also, you have to use `axis=1` for it to work:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x['Col1'].split() if i in x['Col2'].split()]), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    the cat
1           
2    chicken
dtype: object
```

If you want `NULL`, instead of just an empty value, use:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x['Col1'].split() if i in x['Col2'].split()]), axis=1).str.replace('', 'NULL'))
```

Output:

```
0    the cat
1    NULL
2    chicken
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a lambda function here, just check if each word is contained in the string of the same column. The zip() function can be quite useful for column iterations. Here is one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1':{
        1:'the cat crossed a road',
        2:'the dog barked',
        3:'the chicken barked',},
    'col2':{
        1: 'the cat alligator',
        2: 'some words here',
        3: 'chicken soup'}}
)

# output the overlap as a list
output = [
    [word for word in line1.split() if word in line2.split()] 
    for line1, line2 in zip(data_frame['col1'].values, data_frame['col2'].values)
]

# To add your new values a column
data_frame['col3'] = output

# Or, if desired, keep as a list and remove empty rows 
output = [row for row in output if row]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with

```
l=[' '.join([t for t in x if t in y]) for x, y in zip(df1.Col1.str.split(' '),df2.Col2.str.split(' '))]
pd.DataFrame({'Col3':l})
Out[695]: 
      Col3
0  the cat
1         
2  chicken
```